# Returning socket.io object is not usable outside the scope in client.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sockets

I have a client.js and a server.js, in server.js i'm connected to mysql table, and sending queries from client to server. as i get the queries results into the socket.on('event',function(queryResult{...}))
in client.js i can't use the result outside that scope (inside client.js but outside that scope)

**all connections are done locally with a port at localhost.**

index.html:

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="includes/client.js"></script>

<body>
    <div id="getQueryStr"></div>
</body>
```

server.js:

```
var io     = require('socket.io').listen(3000);
var mysql  = require('mysql');  
.
.
.
io.sockets.on('newQuery', function(newQuery){

    MySql_Connection.query(newQuery)

        .on('result', function(queryResultsData){
            queryResultsArr.push(queryResultsData);
        })

        .on('end', function(){
            socket.emit('query results', queryResultsArr);
        });
});
```

client.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    var html=''; 
    var tempStr='';

    $('input#centerSearchInp').bind('keypress', function(e){

        if(e.keyCode==13){

            socket.on('query results', function(queryResult){

                html = queryResult[0].firstName;
                $('#getQueryStr').html(html);        //////OK!
                tempStr = html;
            });
            alert(tempStr);      //////////NOT OK!
        }

    }
});
```

I have tried using innerText and all kind of stuff but no metter what i'm doing, i just not able to use this data outside that scope.

Comment: when you `alert(tempStr);`, the `query results` event may not fired yet, so it's value is still empty.

Comment: but html and tmpStr are globals and queryResult[0].firstName holds the value for sure and so has html var, so why cant it be used out there as an initiated string?

Comment: and if so as you say, how do i get it to be fired?

Comment: Yes they are global, but when you call `alert(tempStr);`, the callback for `query results` may not run yet. for example, your search in mysql last 10s, then, `queryResult[0].firstName` will be executed after 10s, but `alert(tempStr);` runs immediately, not 10s later.

Comment: so how should i handle this situation? i'm kinda new with node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write a function with callback for the alert,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    var html=''; 
    var tempStr='';
    $('input#centerSearchInp').bind('keypress', function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==13){
            socket.on('query results', function(queryResult){
                getTempStr(queryResult, function(tempStr){
                  alert(tempStr); 
                }); 
            });
        }
    }
});

function getTempStr(queryResult, callback){
  html = queryResult[0].firstName;
  $('#getQueryStr').html(html);        
  callback(html);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the alert displays an empty box.
Where are you importing the 'server.js' file ?

you may want to try not having 'var' as declaration of tempStr.

Comment: yes, it displays an empty box, what do you mean by importing server.js

Comment: i don't need to import it im communicating with socket.io